# Javascript scroll eventHandler only working when I'm logged in in Wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

Trying to make a plugin in javascript. The code is working fine except the scroll event which only fires when I'm logged in Wordpress.

The rest of the code (hopefully all) is working as it should when I'm logged out (or in a new session from an incognito window) but this just won't fire up. Why is that?

I'm trying something like this:

```
  document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
     if (window.scrollY > 250) {
        run();
     }
  });
```

Comment: There is nothing in this bit of code that wouldn't run logged in or not.  How is this enqueued or loaded?  Do you have errors in the console when logged in or not logged in?  Show run().

Comment: I'm in an early stage of development so I quickly added the js file in function.php using add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jsfunction' );

Comment: Do you mean its not running in the admin area?

Comment: nope, it's not running at all, in the main page. When I scroll nothing happens when logged out. (working when logged in). It seems very strange, I thought it's something related to Wordpress.

Comment: run() is adding a cookie and a class .... function run() {
    if (counter < 1) {
      counter += 1;
      setCookie(
        '_cookie',
        '{"content in an object"}',
        30
      );
      element.classList.add('close');
    }
  }
}

Comment: Your script should load regardless of if your logged in or not.  So it must be something inside the script.  Try putting console.log in a couple different spots.

Comment: I thought this as well. I'll keep checking and come back when I find anything else. I also have a "window.scrollTo(0, 0);" that won't fire when logged out. Really strange. Thank you